# Vitex negundo - Unintentional Pruning of tree

Tags: trees, pruning

I have been growing Vitex negundo at my home near to the road, and due to its medicinal values, i see that people often tend to break its branches or leaves , leaving the tree devoid of leaves.

I am really worried that it would affect the tree's growth. Also, i am not sure, how this unintentional pruning would affect a species like Vitex negundo.

Comment: The one I'm familiar with is Vitex agnus-castus, but, although your plant may tolerate some pruning which leaves half the plant intact, if the leaves are constantly being removed to the point where there are rarely any, it may not survive. I'm finding it difficult to find out how to take cuttings or propagate  Vitex negundo, but if you could propagate it, you could grow it elsewhere, somewhere it won't constantly be cropped. If I find anything, I'll do an answer...

Comment: @bamboo Michael Dirr wrote a wonderful book called *The Reference Manual for Woody Plant Propagation*, it's mostly geared towards the production nursery but very informative none the less.  He states that V. negundo is easy to root, and propagation is similar to V. agnus-castus.  Basically he suggests this - take softwood cutting in May-July before the inflorescences appear.  Dip in root-tone, and plant in a peat moss:perlite mix and mist until rooting starts.  Stop misting as soon as as roots appear.

Comment: @Ben been out, but finally found a link specific to this plant to post - if the plant is able to produce flowers, growing from seed looks like the simplest option, otherwise, softwood or semi ripe cuttings, as you suggest.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the info. Would surely follow it for propagation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit taken occasionally won't be an issue, but if the plant is regularly being stripped of its leaves, it may eventually kill it.

It seems this plant is very easy to raise from seed, so next time it flowers, collect the seeds and start new plants, with the intention of planting at least one well away from the road. Alternatively, semi ripe cuttings with a heel, grown on in a frame, may give a reasonable success rate. More information in this link; details of propagation are towards the end http://tropical.theferns.info/viewtropical.php?id=Vitex+negundo